# In Star Wars: Age of Rebellion, what is an weapon/armor "Improvement"?

Tags: star-wars-age-of-rebellion

In the Star Wars Age of Rebellion Core (not beta) rule book, for the Ace: Gunner talent tree, one of the listed options is Jury Rigged:

> Choose 1 weapon, armor, or other item and give it a permanent improvement while it remains in use.

What exactly is an "Improvement"? I see Item Qualities, and Item Mods, but nothing that is clearly an "Improvement".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the answer to this one, and possibly a bunch of other Specialization tree talent descriptions that might not be 100% clear, and have a very important piece of advice for anyone running this system: **Read the definition in the Talents Chapter, not the summary in the Specialization tree description.**

In this case, I'm pretty sure "improvement" was specifically used because it is *not* used anywhere else, as the Jury Rigged talent has a very specific list of what it can do defined in the Talents chapter.